# "took a stool for myself"

Tags: phrase-usage

> Tom grabbed an armchair, dragged it to the middle of the room, and motioned for her to sit. Then took a stool for himself and sat down across from her.

Is "took a stool for himself" correct? Is it what a native speaker would write in this context?

Comment: Why are you "suspicious"? Would you still think it was "odd" if *Tom took a **chair** for himself and sat down*?

Comment: No, it's not the stool/chair part. It's more the "for himself" part.

Comment: "Then *he* took a stool for himself", but yes, it sounds fine. Dragging an armchair about sounds less plausible (unless Tom wants back problems!) but it might be fine in context.

Comment: *Tom poured a gin and tonic and gave it to her. Then **poured a brandy for himself** and sat down next to her.* Idiomatically, that would often / usually be phrased with ***to pour*** being used ***ditransitively*** (referencing both a direct ***and*** an indirect object, without using prepositions), as *Then **poured himself a brandy** and sat down.* For no easily-expressed reason, native speakers would be far less likely to use the ditransitive form in your exact context, but there's nothing syntactically wrong with *Then **took himself a stool** and sat down*.